# How to call the REST method POST /wallet/{name}/setDefault using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have been working on Hyperledger composer for my project. I am trying to build a multi user web app. But I can't however, call the REST method POST /wallet/{name}/setDefault.

[image: /wallet/{name}/setDefault]

I used the code below to do a POST request but it returns an error "Unhandled error for request POST /api/wallet/admin%40sample/setDefault: Error: Authorization Required"

```js
function myLogin(){

    var id = document.getElementById("bId").value;
    var signIn = id + "@sample";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "http://localhost:3000/api/wallet/" + id + "%40sample/setDefault";
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var obj ={
      "name": signIn
    }
    var data = JSON.stringify(obj);
    xhr.send(data);
    console.log(url);
  }
```

I have used Github oauth and had already given authorization to each and every participant in the network. But still, it shows the Error.

Comment: Just a comment: snippet does not make sense here since the code uses local server

Comment: Can you explain the bit about Github OAuth? The request in your question does not contain any authorisation data. Typically you would add an `Authorization` request header

Comment: Please provide more details. Where you send the token? etc.

Comment: @Phil Not necessarily; it can be in the request body

Comment: Seems you're missing the `access_token` query param or `X-Access-Token` request header ~ https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html#authenticating-to-the-rest-server-using-an-http-or-rest-client

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I did say _"typically"_. As it turns out, this API supports a request header or query parameter